# Wider default date range in PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, date-range

I am using PostgreSQL 10 and I see in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-datetime.html) that the `date` type has min range 4713 BC. Is there any way to have even lower mins, like 5000BC ? Or I should come up with my own solution?

Comment: You probably are looking to store hunter-gatherer customer details!

Comment: yes- you have to come with your own solution - as ugly as saving date in text on int and perform ALL mathematics yourself I'm afraid. but really - what precise date you want to store?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Its about a cultural/historical project, so ancient eras and dates have to be defined. I look for precise in years. Saving just ancient years will be fine, just like 5000BC, but this will also require a `date` type. This is why I cannot stop to 4713. What if a battle happened in 5000BC? Imagine a historian trying to insert 5000BC and getting an error!

Comment: @KaushikNayak I dont get what you said, sorry. Rephrase maybe? Thanks

Comment: I'm not good in history, of course we probably know more precise dates since 16th century. I think you can do some ugly hack like storing 5000 BC as 1000 BC and -4K in other field with default null, but such wheel will require knowing earliest possible date of course and some function or `case when` statement, or `+ interval -4k` construct. well - no - as soon as I tried proposing the ideas - I see how not reliable any solution would be here... probably you better define strict rue, that dates are kept until 4713 BC and earlier dates are kept in text and do not participate in date operations

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to build a custom solution, like saving the dates as two fields, e.g. a `date` and an extra `smallint` offset.

Maybe the cleanest way would be to define your own data type that internally uses `date` for more recent values and `smallint` for older dates. You can define your own set of operators on this type and use it like a normal date.

Comment: Yes,I was thinking the same thing. What if I store all the dates as default AC, and there is also a boolean (0, BC / 1, AC) and I can then save or render the dates accordingly? The "problem" is, if I want to extract the century out of a BC, I will also have to do (-1) before I render it back to the UI. Do you think that is possible or viable ?

Comment: It is possible, but the whole enterprise opens a lot of questions. Did February 20000 BC have 28 or 29 days? I think that once you start going into questions like this, you'll abandon the idea to store dates before 4000 BC. Maybe you should define your own data type - I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. I think will go for the simplest solution. I will have a "eraBC" table for eras, containing `int` range for centuries and `int` range for just years. Users will just insert `int` for BC years and thats it...